# Pandas Groupby - Calculate percentage of values per group total value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this Pandas group by statement:

```py
df['teams'].groupby(train_sub['outcome']).value_counts()
```

which returns something like this :

```
outcome | teams 
--------|----------------|-----
  win   | Man utd        | 120
        | Chelsea        | 75
        | Arsenal        | 10
--------|----------------|------
  loss  | Man utd        | 30
        | Chelsea        | 75
        | Arsenal        | 150
```

For each team, I want to show the percentage per outcome of the team's total (not the total entries in the dataframe). So something like this:

```
outcome | teams 
--------|----------------|-----
  win   | Man utd        | 0.80
        | Chelsea        | 0.5
        | Arsenal        | 0.0625
--------|----------------|------
  loss  | Man utd        | 0.20
        | Chelsea        | 0.5
        | Arsenal        | 0.9375
```

Please how do I get this outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproducing the dataset like you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['outcome'] = ['win', 'win', 'win', 'loss', 'loss', 'loss']
df['teams'] = ['manu', 'chelsea', 'arsenal', 'manu', 'chelsea', 'arsenal']
df['points'] = [120, 75, 10, 30, 75, 150]
grouped = df.groupby(['outcome', 'teams'])['points'].sum()
```

My `grouped` variable now looks like yours.

```
                 points
outcome teams          
loss    arsenal     150
        chelsea      75
        manu         30
win     arsenal      10
        chelsea      75
        manu        120
```

---

### Solution:

`grouped` in your case is result of `df['teams'].groupby(train_sub['outcome']).value_counts()`. So, just do:

```
grouped / grouped.groupby(level = 1).sum()
```

Output:

```
outcome teams    points     
loss    arsenal  0.9375
        chelsea  0.5000
        manu     0.2000
win     arsenal  0.0625
        chelsea  0.5000
        manu     0.8000
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @ankur

What if I wanted the entire output to stay as it is but only the points column to be sorted in descending order for each category.

Comment: yeah, so how can I see both the wins and the losses sorted by the highest percentage of each one

Comment: You can first do: `x = (grouped / grouped.groupby(level = 1).sum()).reset_index()` and then do: `x.sort_values(['outcome', 'points'], ascending = [False, False])`